# How do I cut and copy a folder with files in it to another path in PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a folder path f1/f2/.Both f1 and f2 are folders
f2 folder contains somany subfolders say ff0,ff1,ff2,ff3.
f2 also contains a folder called copy_folder.(path is f1/f2/copy_folder).
I need to cut and copy all the contents in ff0,ff1,ff2,ff3 together with the folders(ff0,ff1,ff2,ff3) to path is f1/f2/copy_folder .i.e,after all process, copy_folder should contain ff0,ff1,ff2,ff3 with its contents resectively.Also the same should be get deleted from the old folder .i.e from folder f2

Actually I did this in php 5.3 with function 
'copy'.eg:This is my sample code
mkdir(f1.f2/copy_folder/ff0)   //I made the folder inside copy_folder
copy(f1/f2/ff0/t1.exe,copy_folder/ff0) //copy the contents into ff0 in copy_folder
unlink(f1/f2/ff0)   //there by deleting old folder ff0

I did this in php 5.3.But its not working in php 5.2.1.Is there any issue ?
Iam using zend frame work.
Iam using some details in an array('$arrNewClosedIncidentsDetails')

```
              foreach($arrNewClosedIncidentsDetails as $arrNewClosedDet)    


{                           //iteration of closed incident details there by taking the old path


                $strOldPath = $config->paths->releaseattach.'/'.$arrNewClosedDet['strPatchPath'];  //taking the
```

old path
                    if(is_dir($strOldPath))

{                                                          //if the file is direcory

$strNewFolderPath = $config->paths->closedreleaseattach.'/'.$arrNewClosedDet['strFolderName'];

```
//taking the new folder path to which old folder and sub files have to copied
                        mkdir($strNewFolderPath); 

                                                              //making the directory in new path (with old folder name)
                        chmod($strNewFolderPath, 0777);   

                                                      //giving permission to this created folder
                        $arrNewFolderRelatedFiles = scandir($strOldPath);  

                                    //scan all files from old folder 
                        foreach($arrNewFolderRelatedFiles as
```

$objNewFolderRelatedFiles) {                           //iterate all files from old folder

```
                            if($objNewFolderRelatedFiles != '.' && $objNewFolderRelatedFiles != '..')
```

{

```
                                        //remove default dot elements,which will present as the first and second array value

                             if (copy($strOldPath.'/'.$objNewFolderRelatedFiles, $strNewFolderPath.'/'.$objNewFolderRelatedFiles)) {
```

//copy all files which are traced into corresponding new folders which has been created in new path
                                     chmod($strNewFolderPath.'/'.$objNewFolderRelatedFiles, 0777);                                         //give permission to all files which are created in new folder

```
                                      unlink($strOldPath.'/'.$objNewFolderRelatedFiles);                                               //delete the files from old folder 
                                 }
                                }
                        }
                         rmdir($strOldPath);                                                                                                //remove all old folders
                }
             }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rename` function. `rename(old_dir_name, new_dir_name)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: If you want to stay on the safe side: try it out on a local copy or make a backup of your project. Which is good practice anyway.... It will work, even in php4. http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: Thank u very much.I will try it.But could you please tell me why copy is not working?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with writing rights. Hard to say with the information available.

Comment: Yes.I checked with rights.its fine ..As I told, ithe porocedure which I explained above is working perfect in php 5.3.But its not working in 5.2.When I click the button to 'move files',no error is occuring.It just stays as it is.Is there any possibility of missiong some libraries or something related with copy.Any way I am giving my code

Comment: Instead of me checking here, maybe you can check the error logs of your server & see if that brings something up. Does the 'rename' function work?

Comment: Thank you very much for the advise.I came to know that both the copy and rename will work.Any ways, I had already checked the debug log,but couldnt get any error.Actually the problem was that the file permission you were talking about.I had not set the permission for the folders inside the main folder and that was the issue.Now, its working fine....Rename function also worked .Let me conclude that both copy and rename will work in both php 5.3 and 5.2.1.Thank you for the valuable informations .